# export registry using c++

Tags: c++, registry

I am trying to export Registry from C++ using `_popen` but it seems that the registry is not getting exported.

While executing the same command using command prompt, it exports the registry.

My code :

```
FILE *p = _popen("reg export HKLM\SOFTWARE\Agent C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.reg", "r");
```

Can anyone tell me, what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a Windows application or a Console one? `_popen` only works in the latter.

Comment: See [RegSaveKeyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724919(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You need to escape *all* of your backticks, not just some of them. Frankly I'm shocked you didn't get compiler warnings telling you `\S`, `\A` are unknown escape sequences.

Comment: @Angew This one is for Windows service.

Comment: @Jinul Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx, a non-console application cannot use `_popen` (see "Note" beneath "Return value" heading).

Comment: @WhozCraig I also tried it earlier but no luck. `reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Agent C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.reg`

Comment: @Jinul Other than putting in a EOF consumption loop, I tried the same thing on a regular x86 and x64 console app built with vs 2015. No problems.

Comment: @Angew Window services can be implemented as console apps.  And, in any case, a service can spawn a process for a console app (even `cmd.exe`), you just won't see the console window onscreen.